# How to make changes in PySimpleGui app persistent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

here is my app so far

```
import PySimpleGUI as pg
from pathlib import Path

column_goals_checks = [
    [pg.Text('Here are your short term goals! ')],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g1'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_1')],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g2'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_2')],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g3'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_3')],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g4'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_4')],
    [pg.Push(), pg.Text('--------------And long term goals!--------------'), pg.Push()],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g5'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_5')],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g6'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_6')],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g7'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_7')],
    [pg.Checkbox('blank', key='g8'), pg.Button('<-- Edit', key='g_8')]
]
column_goals_notepad = [
    [pg.Multiline('blank', size=(45, 20), )]
]

layout_goals = [
    [pg.Column(column_goals_checks), pg.Column(column_goals_notepad)]
]

layout_calendar = [
    [pg.VPush()],
    [pg.Text('calendar')],
    [pg.VPush()]
]
tabgroup = [[
    pg.TabGroup([[pg.Tab('Goals', layout_goals, border_width=20),
                  pg.Tab('Calendar', layout_calendar, border_width=20)
                  ]])
]]


win = pg.Window('Main', tabgroup)
while True:
    e, v = win.read()
    if e == pg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if e == 'g_1':
        win['g1'].update(text=pg.popup_get_text('Name Goal: '))
```

I'm making this app to track my progress and keep myself accountable for learning Python. But once i'm finished with it i'd like for everything i enter to be persistent and not reset each time i close the app. So how do i save it or write everything somewhere so that it keeps the input data constant.

Comment: it doesn't have special function to persistent values. You have to use standard functions `open()`, `write()`, `close()` to save data when you close program - and also `open()`, `read()`, `close()` to load data again when you start program - and use these value to generate GUI with these values.. You can also use some modules to write in special formats - ie. `json`, `csv`, `excel`, `ini`

Comment: Refer [User Setting API](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#user-settings-api)

Answer (score 1):

As Jason has mentioned you can use the User Settings API build into PySimpleGUI. Here is a small code snippet to help getting started:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# set filename and path where your user settings will be saved. 
# This is optional, otherwise a default path is used.
sg.user_settings_filename("user_settings.json", r"C:\Temp")
# use a set of key, value pairs to save a value
sg.user_settings_set_entry("key", "value")
# get entry from settings file
my_value = sg.user_settings_get_entry("key")
```

Comment: Ok so for the key value pair can I use the key of the button and the value that button returns? like                                sg.user_settings_set_entry("g1", "v[g1]")                                             or do i have to link the value of the button to a unique key placed in the user settings dict? thanks

Comment: The way I do it is using `sg.user_settings_get_entry("key")` as the default value in any widget. The widgets functions/methods usually come with a `default_value` parameter.